# Don't understand cause of TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to open a dictionary with many different objects of different types within it. I want to deconstruct this code such to give me the objects in its simplest forms which are strings.

This is my code:

```
def open_it(file):
    if type(file)==dict:
        keys = file.keys()
        for key in keys:
            open_it(file[key])
    elif type(file)==list:
        for i in file:
            open_it(file[i])
    else:
        print(file)
        print("_____________")
        
open_dictionary(dic)
```

Why is this problem happening?

Comment: `i` is not an index into the list; it's an *element* of the list. `open_it(i)`.

Answer (score 1):

These lines

```
for i in file:
    open_it(file[i])
```

should just be

```
for i in file:
    open_it(i)
```

because `i` is the element of the list itself, *not* the index to the element.

As an aside, it is typically preferred to use

```
if isinstance(file, dict):
```

instead of

```
if type(file) == dict:
```